# simple grails rc1 integration test failure

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing

I'm trying to run a very simple integration test and keep getting this error:

```
Caused an ERROR
No signature of method: com.ra.EquipmentTests.assertNotNull() is applicable for argument types: (com.ra.equipment.Equipment) values: [com.ra.equipment.Equipment : 1]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.ra.EquipmentTests.assertNotNull() is applicable for argument types: (com.ra.equipment.Equipment) values: [com.ra.equipment.Equipment : 1]
    at com.ra.EquipmentTests.testSomething(EquipmentTests.groovy:27)
```

the classes and test in question:

```
    class Equipment {
    static hasMany = [pixes: Pix]
    static constraints = {
    }
}
class Pix {
    def Equipment equipment
    static belongsTo = [Equipment]
    static constraints = {
    }
}



class EquipmentTests {
    @Before
    void setUp() {
        // Setup logic here
    }

    @After
    void tearDown() {
        // Tear down logic here
    }

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        def equipment = new Equipment()

        //assertNull equipment.pixes
        assertNotNull equipment.save()
    }
}
```

I'm using Grails rc1 and Groovy 1.7.8, as embarrassing as all this is any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test classes need to extend one of the grails/groovy test classes, like

`GrailsUnitTestCase` or `GroovyTestCase`.

Here is some [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/9.%20Testing.html).

Comment: ... ouch, that did it. I never bothered to think of it as the test was generated by IntelliJ ide. Hm, so thanks, it's a better lesson than I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1):

in Grails 2.0 You should use the `@TestFor(Equipment)` annotation instead of extending `GrailsUnitTestCase` or others.

> Grails 1.3.x and below used the grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase class
>   hierarchy for testing in a JUnit 3 style. Grails 2.0.x and above
>   deprecates these test harnesses in favour of mixins that can be
>   applied to a range of different kinds of tests (JUnit 3, Junit 4,
>   Spock etc.) without subclassing

- http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/testing.html

Comment: ... but why do the integration test examples extend GroovyTestCase? http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting